# Is the rigidity of telescoping tripod legs affected by orientation (inversion)?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm hoping these are simple questions for someone here.
Most tripods with telescoping legs have the smallest diameter tube at the bottom. I'm wondering if there is any physical advantage to this.

It seems to me that if the legs were inverted and the smallest tubes were affixed to the top plate they would have less ability to move than when free floating at the bottom. The weight of the platform load would have less leverage (a shorter arm) on the small diameter tubes, but I'm not sure if that matters in terms of flexing as the total arm (leg length) would remain the same.

And what are the vibration dampening characteristic differences between large diameter/small diameter tubing given the same material specifications?

The large diameter tube would/could have inherently larger diameter feet which should be of some benefit if nothing else.

Comment: I think you want the feet to be as small as possible. In fact there should be point contacts, so that three points define a plane. With wide feet, each foot will try to force different orientation on the tripod (so the foot is flat) causing instability and bending on the legs. You want reaction forces only, and no reaction moments.